# I can't input data into the Stripe fields using Selenium during test payments

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, stripe-payments

I can't input data into the Stripe fields using Selenium during test payments. The test crashes on timeout all the time, I just can't get it to interact with the stripe fields...

I'm having trouble interacting with the Stripe fields. I switch to the iframe, but still encounter a timeout, and the data is not entered into the field. The locators seem to be correctly composed, as I can find the desired element in the DOM tree when searching with them.
If necessary, you can use the login and password from the code to take a look at the input field on the payment page.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver, url):
        self.driver = driver
        self.url = url

    def open(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def element_is_visible(self, locator, timeout=5):
        return wait(self.driver, float(timeout)).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))

    def waiting_expected_url(self, expected_url, timeout=5):
        wait(self.driver, float(timeout)).until(EC.url_to_be(expected_url))

    def switch_to_new_tab(self):
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
        url = self.driver.current_url
        return url

    def switch_to_iframe(self, locator, timeout=5):
        iframe = wait(self.driver, float(timeout)).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(locator))
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


def test_invalid_ccc_4242_4242_4242_4241(driver):
    sign_in_page = BasePage(driver, 'https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol')
    sign_in_page.open()
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(.,"sign in")]')).click()
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.ID, 'email')).send_keys('ivanbarsukov738+1@gmail.com')
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.ID, 'password')).send_keys('test111')
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"] > span')).click()
    sign_in_page.waiting_expected_url('https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol')
    driver.get("https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/glp/plus")
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button > div > img[alt='Plus']")).click()
    sign_in_page.switch_to_new_tab()
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.XPATH, "//div[p[contains(text(), '1 month')]]/following-sibling::div/button"), timeout=10).click()
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.ID, 'cardHolder')).send_keys("John Doe")
    sign_in_page.switch_to_iframe((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="Secure card number input frame"]'))
    sign_in_page.element_is_visible((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="Secure card number input frame"]/following-sibling::input')).send_keys("4242424242424241")
    time.sleep(4)
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be and can offer assistance? I'll figure out the rest of the fields on my own based on the analogy.

Comment: It's not recommended to tests Stripe UI or any other UI component that you don't own. You need to mock these component as they are external and production ready   ones. In other words you are trying to test a product that has all production features enabled/ including security checks which may prevent the component from being rendering in test environments (considered as non human interactions)

Comment: But I'm not testing the component itself; I need to ensure that after filling in the fields and making a payment in the test environment, the user will have access to certain premium features.
Of course, the test will run on a test environment, not in production, but in the test environment, the Stripe fields have the same properties, and I can't enter data into them.

To solve this problem, will removing the attribute with a script help: aria-hidden="true"?
And how should I do it? Or how can I do it better and correctly? Is there any reference on how to cover this with automated tests?